# What does etree.xpath function of python lxml library do?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, elementtree

I understand that `etree` object from `lxml` library is a tree representation of a xml document. It is not clear to me what `.xpath` function does. I just need to know how to interpret its argument and its output. I saw the following example of use:

```
tree.xpath('.//' + tagname)
html.xpath("string()")
html.xpath("//text()")
```

What do all these `string()` and `//text()` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see there is XPath. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath
The xpath() function will take a valid XPath and return the result. You could say XPath is a query language for xml documents.

This should clear things up: http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method

Comment: please specify an example. The result has a weird type